# Как передать значения глобальных переменных в функцию GeoCode (API Яндекс Карт)?

Tags: javascript, api, яндекс-карты

У меня есть глобальный массив с названиями населенных пунктов. В цикле запускается функция GeoCode для определения координат метки по названию, которая сразу же и расставляет эти метки. Но внутри функции я не могу использовать значения из своего массива (подробнее в комментариях в коде). Как это исправить?

```
ymaps.ready(function (){
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map_reader",{
        center: [56.0102,92.8551],
        zoom: 10,
        controls: ['zoomControl']
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });
    
var pl_name = [ //Вот мой массив
        'Красноярск',
        'Красноярский край, Березовка'
    ];
    
var mClust = new ymaps.Clusterer({clusterDisableClickZoom:true});
    
    for (var i = 0; i<pl_name.length; i++) { //Запускаю цикл для создания меток
        var mgc = ymaps.geocode(pl_name[i], {results: 1}).then( //Та самая функция, которая определяет координаты по названию
            function(res){ //А вот и виновница - вложенная в нее функция
                var mgo = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                    crds = mgo.geometry.getCoordinates();
                mgo.options.set('preset', 'islands#darkBlueDotIconWithCaption');
                mgo.properties.set('hintContent', pl_name[i]); // Вот тут я хочу взять значение из массива, но такой вариант не работает
            mClust.add(mgo);
            });
    }
    
    myMap.geoObjects.add(mClust);
});
```

Comment: Замените `for (var i = 0` на `for (let i = 0`. Дело в асинхронности, не во вложенной функции.

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо большое)